# xcode 12 firebase notification when app in background how to do a reload if the app have a opened webview

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, wkwebview

I implemented firebase notification in Xcode 12 via cocoapod and basic step by step... notification ARE working all nice and good, even when app in background.

this tutorial : https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/

the only thing I need is this condition : when App in background and user hit the notification, it opens the APP, but I want the webview to reload.

i think it would be in this part of the code

```
// [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

but what code and I add to reload the view ?

Answer (score -1):

// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification
// With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
// Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
print("Message ID: (messageID)")
}

```
    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
    
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

Comment: you copy pasted my question ?